# pandas groupby create new columns based on col1 containing value of col2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to group by and create columns for each value of col1 and they should contain the value of col2. And example dataframe:

```py
data = {'item_id': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3},
 'feature_category_id': {0: 56, 1: 62, 2: 68, 3: 56, 4: 72},
 'feature_value_id': {0: 365, 1: 801, 2: 351, 3: 802, 4: 75}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I want to groupby item_id, create as many columns as feature_category_id and fill them with the feature_value_id.

The resultant df for the example would look like this:

```py
data = {'item_id': {0: 2, 1: 3},
 'feature_56': {0: 801, 1: 802},
 'feature_62': {0: 365, 1: None},
 'feature_68': {0: 351, 1: None},
 'feature_72': {0: None, 1: 75},}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Where features not present for a certain  item_id (but present for at least one item_id) are NaN.

Which would be the most optimal operation to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is pandas [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function. It does exactly what you want:

```
# Change df shape
result = df.pivot(index="item_id", columns="feature_category_id")

# Change the axis labels
result.columns = ["feature_" + str(x[1]) for x in result.columns]
result = result.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   item_id  feature_56  feature_62  feature_68  feature_72
0        2       365.0       801.0       351.0         NaN
1        3       802.0         NaN         NaN        75.0
```

Comment: Hi! That seems to make it work for the example so is a valid solution. When I try this on a bigger dataset I get `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. I made sure I have no duplicate rows and I also tried reseting the index of the dataframe prior to the pivot. Any idea why this could be? Is a public dataset so I can share it with you if you want to try it out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17e6DMaSona1N_qdLOt_BeDKcVrNA9nUM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can use `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id', 'feature_category_id'])` before the pivot function. Then it works.

Comment: You can only use it if each `item_id` and `feature_id` combination is unique. Otherwise, it does not know which value to take. Another way to handle duplicate entries is [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) with which you can for example take the mean of duplicated values.